# How to extract a zip file to directory and overwrite?

Tags: vb.net, zip, overwrite

I made a little program that downloads a .zip file from my website and then later it installs in a specific directory. It works fine unless a file with the same name already exists, then I get an error. This is the code I have.

```
If Form1.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    Label4.Text = "Downloading Test File!"
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://www.example.com/TestFile.zip"), Directory + "\TestFile.zip")
    While wc.IsBusy = True
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test File")
End If

'Install
If Form1.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Directory + "\TestFile.zip", Directory_Select.TextBox1.Text)
    ListBox2.Items.Add("Test File")
End If
```

So for example, if the files inside "TestFile.zip" have the same name as Install location, it will give me following error:

> The file 'filePath` already exists.

It doesn't finish extracting because a file with the same name already exists. Deleting the file beforehand is not a good solution because there will be multiple files with the same name.

**How can I replace while extracting?**

Also is there a way to pause the program till the file finishes extracting since some files are large and it takes some time before they are extracted.

Thanks in advance for helping me out, I am new and still learning. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Define what you mean by "pause the program". This seems like a WinForms app so while extracting, the UI thread will be blocked anyway; is this what you mean by "pause"? Or do you mean the opposite (i.e., to keep the program responsive while extracting)?

Comment: `because there will be multiple files with the same name.`, sounds like you have bigger problems. How can you have a same file with the same name and type in the same directory more than once? On another note, remove the `DoEvents`, they are code smell.

Comment: @Codexer I think the OP meant to say _"there will be multiple files in the archive having names that already exist in the target folder"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `ExtractToDirectory` method doesn't support overwriting files by default, the [`ExtractToFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttofile) method has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttofile#System_IO_Compression_ZipFileExtensions_ExtractToFile_System_IO_Compression_ZipArchiveEntry_System_String_System_Boolean_) which takes a second *boolean* variable that allows you to overwrite the file being extracted. What you can do is to iterate over the files inside the archive and extract them one by one using `ExtractToFile(filePath, True)`.

I have created an extension method which does just that and have been using it for a while. Hope you find it useful!

Add the following module to your project:

```
Module ZipArchiveExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Sub ExtractToDirectory(archive As ZipArchive,
                                  destinationDirPath As String, overwrite As Boolean)
        If Not overwrite Then
            ' Use the original method.
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirPath)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
            Dim fullPath As String = Path.Combine(destinationDirPath, entry.FullName)

            ' If it's a directory, it doesn't have a "Name".
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath))
            Else
                entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath, True)
            End If
        Next entry
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Usage:**

```
Using archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archiveFilePath)
    archive.ExtractToDirectory(destPath, True)
End Using
```

**Side note:** Don't concatenate strings to form a path out of its parts; use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Answering all your comments here. @Ahmed Abdelhameed, what i mean by pausing the program is: while the program is extracting first file to destination, it doesnt continue with the code after / it finishes extracting first file before it moves on to next file. I will try your code in couple of hours. Thanks for that.  @ Coderex. The problem is that all the zip files extract to same destination. The software is basically installing game addons by replacing game files so thats why its same and there are many with same name.  Thanks for your time